# Dynamic dns client stops updating when login off Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, dynamic-dns

Running a dynamic dns updater software on Windows server 2008 R2, when I log off the software stops updating, I concluded that I have to look for a dynamic dns client running as service, I found this task a bit heavy since there is a big variety on the net, it needs a long time to make the right choice as many details are to pay attention to, free, masked fees, fees, installed on machine, configured on router, trusted, not trusted, compliant with OS, not,  ...

That's why I am here to ask for help on this matter, I would like to be advised by skilled people, to find a trusted free dns updater (client) for Windows which can run as service, and maybe which can send email when update fails.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem so outlandish to me. I run a number of servers at home off of my cable internet dynamic ip address and I use a dynamic DNS client to update my public ip address so that I can host my own external email and web sites from home. Have a look here:

http://dyn.com/support/clients/

http://freedns.afraid.org/scripts/freedns.clients.php

http://www.dynamicdnsclient.com/

http://www.opendns.com/support/dynamic_ip_downloads/

http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/

Your router might also have a built in dynamic DNS client.

**EDIT**

I should point out that I don't use a dynamic ip address on my server but I do run a dynamic DNS client on my server in order to update my public DNS zones with the dynamic ip address from my cable provider so that I can host publicly available web and email services. I slightly misunderstood the nature of the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, the most important thing I was looking for trough my question is to substitute the currently used dynamic client software that stops updating IP as soon as I log off, with another dynamic client software which could run as service (backgroud), and which stays always in sync. I have found this: [http://noeld.com/dynsite.asp](http://noeld.com/dynsite.asp), looking forward your recommandations...

Comment: The domain name should stay where it is currently, I do not want to transfer it to another company only because it provides dyndns services.

Comment: After checking your links, I have found what I looked for, thanks again joeqwerty.

Comment: Glad to help...